# onClick redirect button to another component react routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to click on **View Menu** button on the Home page and redirect it to **Menu** file.
So when i click on **View Menu** I can see the **Menu Available**
I want to click on **View Menu** button on the Home page and redirect it to **Menu** file.
So when i click on **View Menu** I can see the **Menu Available**

**Home File**

```
import React from 'react'
import Restaurant from "./Restaurant";
const Home = () => {
  
    return (
        <div className="homeMain">
        <img className="home_img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/b5/d7/53b5d70023efa05ec6797b25df413b73.jpg"/>
        <h1 className="home_h1 text-center">Maryam's Restaurant</h1>
        
        **want to insert button here **
       
        </div>
    )
}



export default Home;
```

**Restaurant File i.e to be displayed onClick**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import menuList from "./menuList"
import Breakfast from "./Breakfast";
import Home from "./Home";
import WebPages from "./WebPages";

const uniqueList = () => [... new Set (
  menuList.map((curElem) =>
  {
    return curElem.category;
  })
), "All", ]

const Restaurant = () =>
{
  const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState(menuList);
  const [data, setData] = useState(uniqueList);

  const filterItem = (category) =>
  {
    if(category === "All")
    {
      setMenuData(menuList);
      return;
    }
    const updatedList = menuList.filter((curElement) =>
    {
      return curElement.category === category;
    });
    setMenuData(updatedList);
  }
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <App filterItem={filterItem} data={data} />
        <Breakfast menuData={menuData}/>
        
      </div>
 )
}
export default Restaurant;
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this,
First in your App.js
use these lines of code along with others (you can change the path name these are only for you to understand).

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Restaurant from "./components/Restaurant";

const App ()=>{

return (

<>
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/Restaurent" exact>
            <Restaurent />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
</>
);
}
```

And in Home File
use this

```
import React from 'react'
import Restaurant from "./Restaurant";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"; 

const Home = () => {
  
    return (
        <div className="homeMain">
        <img className="home_img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/b5/d7/53b5d70023efa05ec6797b25df413b73.jpg"/>
        <h1 className="home_h1 text-center">Maryam's Restaurant</h1>
        
        <Link to="/Restaurant" className="button">Open Menu</Link>

 
        </div>
    )
}



export default Home;
```

let me know if you got any doubts in the comments.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do so:
add a Link component

**Home File**

```js
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

...

<Link to="/Restaurant" className="home_button">View Menu</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's a case where we have to programmatically route stuff, They try to use it like this. But this needs a dom-manipulation manually, which is not recommended in React! Use Link Component wherever possible. But still, we end up in a situation like this, where you can use this approach.

```
function Component(){

const handleClickEvent = () =>{
    window.history.pushState("domain","title","pathToGo");
    window.history.go()
}


return (
       <Button onClick={() => handleClickEvent()}>Button</Button>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use navigate method so have a look for that link

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

and I think you can try that

```
import {useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

set that instance inside the component you need to navigate from  
const navigate = useNavigate()


const onClickHandler = (event){
event.preventDefault()
navigate('/Restaurant', {
              state: {    // optional if you need to pass //data but you will need to use "location" to receive this //data on another side 

                position: res.data.position
              },
              replace: true
            })
}
```